# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoDB::find() when try to use collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I have followed structure of mongoDB:

- DB name: `bios`
- user: "fess"
- password: "boo"
- IP: 1.2.3.4
- collection name: bios2

*From MongoVUE:*

[image]

This is my snippets of PHP code:

```
$db = new Mongo('mongodb://fess:boo@1.2.3.4/bios');

// if i remove "bios" it asks default db name

$collection_bios2 = $db->bios2;

$cursor_bios2 = $collection_bios2->find(); // <- here I get error
//  PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MongoDB::find()

...
$db->close();
```

Why I get this error?
I saw other examples and seems that `$collection_bios2` should be collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do you select db? such as

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
// the following two lines are equivalent
$db = $mongo->selectDB("foo");
$db = $mongo->foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. In order to create connection only, 1st off I need create user/pswd for admin:

Through mongoDB CLI:

```
 > use admin
 > use bios
 > db.createUser("fess", "boo");
```

Actually I had user only for `bios` DB

Otherwise it will drop me error:

> Error connecting to MongoDB server Failed to connect to: 1.2.3.4:27017: Authentication failed on database 'admin' with username 'fess': auth fails

**PHP**

```
        // here we create just client (for admin aka root)
        $m = new MongoClient('mongodb://fess:boo@1.2.3.4');

        // and switch to "bios" 
        $db = $m->selectDB("bios");

        $list = $db->listCollections();
        foreach ($list as $collection) {
             Log::Debug(get_class() . " -> testMongoDB", "feederliteRC/U", array("Output" => "collection: $collection"));

        }

         //$db = new Mongo('mongodb://max:bagabu@172.20.0.23/bios');

         //$collection_bios = $db->bios;
         $collection_bios2 = $db->bios2;
```

**Output**

```
 "collection: bios.bios2"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is fine as below. I used "mongodb/mongodb" with composer from packagist. "composer require mongodb/mongodb".

```
require(__DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php");
use MongoDB\Client as MGDClient;

$collection = (new MGDClient(username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/db_name))->db_name->collection_name;

$cursor = $collection->find([],['limit'=>5]);

var_dump($cursor);
```